# Move first item to last position of an array with setInterval() in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setinterval, use-state

I am trying to move the first item of an array to the last position of the array in React, using a `setInterval` function:

```
const [cardOrder, setCardOrder] = useState([card1, card2, card3, card4]);
setInterval(() => {
    setCardOrder(cards.push(cards.shift()))
}, 3000);
```

The first time always works, but the second time I get

```
TypeError: cardsOrder.shift is not a function
```

How can I achieve this result? All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You say "using a setTimout function" and then use `setInterval`, which is not the same as "setTimout" or `setTimeout`. Then you show code which does not use the variable `cardsOrder` but say you're getting an error about `cardsOrder.shift` no being a function. The mismatches between your question text and your code make it difficult to follow the question... Please show the actual code used and the errors produced by that code.

Comment: Apologies, I rushed the question. setInterval was what I meant.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to make it the best it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code, e.g. `cardsOrder` is not defined. Also you are missing some essential stuff, like state management and lifecycle aka hooks. Also not sure why do you need the `i` variable. Anyways, heres a possible, alternative solution:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [arr, setFn] = useState(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']);
  
  useEffect(() => {
     const i = setInterval(() => {
        setFn(([first, ...rest]) => [...rest, first]);
     }, 1000);
     
     return () => clearInterval(i);
  }, []);
  
  return arr.join('\n');
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
   white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because, `[].push()` returns length of the array. So when you do `setOrder(cards.push(cards.shift(i)))` cards will be changed `(Array)` to Number(length of the Array), next time when you call this will become `(number)1.shift` which is not function. That's why you're getting that error.

Change your code to:

```
 setInterval(() => {
   cards.push(cards.shift())
   setOrder([...cards]) // this will work.

   // OR

   const card = cards.shift()
   setOrder([...cards, card])
 }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement swap as Array prototype

```
Array.prototype.swap = function (x, y) {
  var z = this[x];
  this[x] = this[y];
  this[y] = z;
  return this;
}
```

and then use it

```
const array= [{a:'a',b:'b'},{c:'c',d:'d'}];
const newArray = array.swap(0,1)
```

newArray if what are you looking for. Use insted `.swap(0,3)`

Comment: "You can implement swap as Array prototype" but don't, unless you have absolute control over all of the code used in your application and its dependencies. See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552)

Comment: So he can implement as a simple function.